# Overriding Samba calls to unlink and unlinkat

Tags: samba

My attempt is to override calls to unlink/unlinkat when using Samba.
To that effect I wrote a shared library.
I then executed the line:

```
export LD_PRELOAD=<my shared library>
```

and restarted smbd service.
Now if I delete a file from the current directory I can see that my version of unlink is being called but when I do the same via Samba from a different Ubuntu box my overrides aren't being called.
I think it's got to do with the placement of LD_PRELOAD.
I placed it in /etc/samba/smb.conf and /etc/init/smbd.conf but that didn't work and the only file left is /etc/init.d/smbd.
However I don't know where to place the LD_PRELOAD. I did place the LD_PRELOAD in a few places but that didn't work either.
I'm hoping that someone cuold help me out.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Platform: Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

*(I know this is 2 years later. It might still be useful to somebody else.)*

LD_PRELOAD is an environment variable, which needs to be set in smbd's environment.

Since the service is not called from the shell, you have to work with your distribution's startup/service system.

Quick web search tells me Ubuntu 14.04 is using `upstart`, so you'll probably need to put something like:

```
env LD_PRELOAD=<my shared library>
export LD_PRELOAD
```

into `/etc/init/smbd.conf`.

Note that this is an educated guess, so you might need to change a thing or two.